# Parallelize two for loops through c++ list/iterator using OpenMP

Tags: c++, list, parallel-processing, openmp

I would like to parallelize the following structure using OpenMP:

```
for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
{
   for (vector<my_element>::iterator it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); ++it2)
   {
       // code here (it2->process)
   }
}
```

I have tried different approaches but I could not make it work properly. Could you help me?.

I am using gcc 5.3.0, OpenMP 4.0. The solutions I've tried so far with no success are:

Solution 1:

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
{
   for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
   {
   #pragma omp task firstprivate(it)
       for (vector<my_element>::iterator it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); ++it2)
       {
          // code here (it2->process)
       }
   #pragma omp taskwait
   }
}
```

Solution 2:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
   {
      #pragma omp single nowait
      {
          for (vector<my_element>::iterator it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); ++it2)
          {
             // code here (it2->process)
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just wanted to get a general solution. I have already edited the question including the solutions I've tried so far with no success

Comment: Just so we're clear, are you trying to parallelize over the first loop (elements of `data`) or the inner loop (elements of `it`)?

Comment: The main idea is trying to parallelize over the first loop, since the number of elements of `data` ≈ 10^7. Elements  of `it` < 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not call `omp taskwait`.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp single
    {
        for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
        {
        #pragma omp task firstprivate(it)
            for (vector<my_element>::iterator it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); ++it2)
            {
            // code here (it2->process)
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is there any way to run the first loop in different threads (without `single` usage)?

Comment: @Finfa811 It is running in different thread and spawns the tasks which the remaining threads work on. Without `single` all threads would spawn tasks and none would work on them.